# Android Studio "0 test classes found in package" when "rerun failed tests"

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, intellij-idea, robolectric

I am experiencing a very frustrating behaviour on Android Studio, updated to the latest version (3.1.3, buld number #AI-173.4819257), gradle plugin version 3.1.3.
What it happening is that after running my Robolectric based unit tests, clicking on "rerun failed tests", I always get this message:

> 0 test classes found in package 'my-package-name'
>
> Process finished with exit code 254
>
> Empty test suite.

I tried to Invalidate Cache / Restart, update to the latest version of every dependency. Actually I couldn't find any helpful information about this problem, so I am here to ask if someone has experienced a similar behaviour

Here you can find my configuration for the test

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seem it was an Android Studio bug fixed in 3.1.4, as stated here https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/#3-1-0

installing the version 3.1.4 actually fixed the issue